# Dual y axes in Google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to use dual y axes with Google charts.I understand the basics and how it works.

On one y axis, I want `BMI` values and on other `Weight` Values.

I am taking out data from SQL database. However, `BMI` and `Weight` are itself values in a column called `ReadingName`.
So, if I use the query,

```
select * from table where ReadingName = 'BMI' or ReadingName = Weight
```

I get the result set which is serialized into JSON and then forwarded to render charts which again would be retrieved using column Name only.

Now, to have observation values for `BMI` on one yaxis and `Weight` on other, as per the example on GoogleCharts  website, I need to have them as columns.

But I have them only as different  values of same column called `ReadingType`.Is there a work around possible ?

This is how it should look like :
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you'll have to massage the data into a format it understands.  The [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) class provides lots of methods for populating but here is an example:

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    // Start with long data
    var rawData = [
        [new Date(2014, 8, 1), "Weight", 140],
        [new Date(2014, 8, 1), "BMI", 5],
        [new Date(2014, 8, 15), "Weight", 130],
        [new Date(2014, 8, 15), "BMI", 4],
        
        [new Date(2014, 9, 1), "Weight", 120],
        [new Date(2014, 9, 1), "BMI", 3],
        [new Date(2014, 9, 15), "Weight", 120],
        [new Date(2014, 9, 15), "BMI", 3]
    ];
    
    // Create a wide table from the long data
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn("date", "Date");
    data.addColumn("number", "BMI");
    data.addColumn("number", "Weight");
    
    
    var lastDate = null;
    var currentRow = null;
    for (var i=0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
        var date=rawData[i][0];
        var col=rawData[i][1];
        var value=rawData[i][2];
        
        if (lastDate == null) {
            // First pass
            currentRow = [date, null, null];            
        }
        else if (lastDate != date) {
            data.addRow(currentRow);
            currentRow = [date, null, null];      
        }
        
        if (col=="BMI") currentRow[1] = value;
        else if (col=="Weight") currentRow[2] = value;
        
        
        lastDate = date;
    }
    
    if (currentRow != null) data.addRow(currentRow);
    
    

    var options = {

        title: 'Wight & BMI',
        vAxes: [{
            title: "Weight",
            minValue: 0
        }, {
            title: "BMI",
            minValue: 0
        }],
        series: {
            0: { targetAxisIndex:0 },    
            1: { targetAxisIndex:1 }
        },
        interpolateNulls: true
    }


    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart"));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```